# What's the hidden rule of the two groups?

Tags: word-property

[image: Two groups of words]

What's the hidden rule of the two groups?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE and congrats on your first puzzle! If you are interested in learning more about the site (and getting your second badge) consider doing the tour from this link:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 10):

I'm fairly certain I have the first group right but I'm less sure with the second.

First Group:

> Each word has run of 3 letters in alphabetical order. Ai**rst**ream, A**lmn**er, A**stu**te, **Def**lation, **Hij**ack, Acetami**nop**hen, Lau**ghi**ng.

Second Group:

> Each word has a consonant digraph (two letters that spell one sound). **Ps**oriasis, Pu**sh**ed, Pat**ch**ed, **Kn**ifed, Hija**ck**, Acetamino**ph**en, Lau**gh**ing.

Comment: I spotted the second but not the first, well done

Comment: If so, what about the 'ea' in airstream and the 'ti' in deflation?

Comment: He said CONSONANT digraph

Comment: [insert expletive indicating the realization of my error here]